# Pass a jquery var to a php var in Magento 1.7.2 is not working

Tags: jquery, magento, post, load

The following code in Magento 1.7.2 is not working and i don't understand the reasons...

I have the following php code :

```
<div class="input-box">                                             
    <select id="attribute137" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
        <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
        <option><?php echo 'Company1' ?></option>
        <option><?php echo 'Company1' ?></option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="Mydate">
<?php
    echo Time() . '<br/>';
    $company = $_REQUEST['company'];
    echo  'company : ' . $company . $_POST['company'] . '<br/>';
?>
</div>
```

and i try in jquery to push the selected value in post variable "company" like this :

```
jQuery("#attribute137").change(function (){
    jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "./calendar",
       data: {company : 'test'},
       success: function(msg){
         alert( "Data Saved: " + company);
       } 
    });
    jQuery('#Mydate').load('./calendar #Mydate');

});
```

I try too :

```
jQuery.post('/calendar', {'company': jQuery("#attribute137 option:selected").val()});
jQuery('#Mydate').load('./calendar #Mydate');
```

And then, the time is updated when i change on my select, but the variable company is not recovered...
=> the variable company return Null while JQuery("#attribute137 option:selected").val() return the selected value...
So i think the transfer of the variable is not working but i don't understand why...

Do you have an idea why?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is not working? What is the Ajax request returning?

Comment: Hello Pekka, thanks for your attention. I complete my question in order to explain what is not working...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that jQuery chokes on the double usage of the ID `#Mydate`. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Try using a different ID when sending the Ajax snippet, or a class name.

Comment: You are speaking about this line? :jQuery('#Mydate').load('./calendar #Mydate'); In That case, i can add a div Mydate2 wrapping Mydate. Is that what you think i have to do?

Comment: @Arnaud you shouldn't have two elements with the same ID in one document. If you can rename the 2nd element to Mydate2, that should work fine

Comment: I'm sorry, but i only have one div named MyDate... Idon't understand your comment.

Comment: @Arnaud The moment you make your Ajax request, you have two, no?

Comment: @Arnaud I'm not sure I follow. The way your code is written that is simply going to happen. You need to change it so there are no duplicate IDs.

Comment: Ok, i have done like this : <div id=''Mydate'><div id='Mydate2'> with this JQ : jQuery('#Mydate').load('./calendar #Mydate2'); and it's working too, but my POST var is not keeped... So i have the same comportement (Time is uploaded but var is null)